# Where can one learn the structure of caret sign command sets as in install lamp-server^?

Tags: apt, tasksel

To establish a LAMP stack with Ubuntu one could execute in an Ubuntu command line:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
```

The caret indicated it's not a common installation command but rather a command that encapsulates a set of commands.

Where can one learn the structure of caret sign command sets as in `install lamp-server^` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [blog](https://shantanugoel.com/2010/10/23/apt-get-caret/):

> Well, the answer is that the caret symbol is a short form for performing a task that otherwise the program “tasksel” would have done with the given package name.
>
> tasksel is a program to ease the installation of commonly used things that go together for a particular use. e.g. In the above instance of LAMP, the four packages and their dependencies are always used together, so tasksel provides a sort of a meta-package or meta-task that can be run by the user with a single command and then tasksel will take it upon itself to install all of them and set them up correctly for your use.
>
> Now, apt-get provides a way to perform that same task by itself without you having to install tasksel first and all you have to do is to give that same package name to apt-get but just append a caret at the end to tell apt-get that it is a tasksel package/task identifier and not a regular package name in debian/ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Just a conclusion I had. Thanks for the clarification David.